# Day of Week Query with Timezone Enabled

Tags: django, postgresql, timestamp-with-timezone

Consider a simple DB Schema:

```
Table XYZ:
    filter_datetime: DateTime field (With Timezone enabled)
```

Now, if I want to find all XYZ rows where `filter_datetime` occurred on "Monday", that is doable if I ignore the Timezone.

However, how do I query, if I do not want to ignore timezone information?

Also, specifically for my case, I can make sure that `filter_datetime` would have the same timezone. However, once the table is populated, users should be able to query according to different Timezones and get correct results. (That is a user in UTC+6:00 would have different rows when he tries to get Monday rows as opposed to a user who have timezone in UTC-6:00)

Bonus (Not really needed for me to accept the answer): Is it possible via Django ORM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sample:

```
t=# create table xyz(filter_datetime timestamptz);
CREATE TABLE
t=# insert into xyz select generate_series('2018-02-04'::timestamptz,'2018-02-14'::timestamptz,'4 hour'::interval);
INSERT 0 61
```

select (if you don't want to ignore TZ - just don't ignore it):

```
t=# set TimeZone to 'UTC-6:00';
SET
t=# select ctid,filter_datetime at time zone 'UTC' utc, filter_datetime,to_char(filter_datetime,'Day'), extract(dow from filter_datetime)
from xyz
where extract(dow from filter_datetime) = 1
order by 1;
  ctid  |         utc         |    filter_datetime     |  to_char  | date_part
--------+---------------------+------------------------+-----------+-----------
 (0,6)  | 2018-02-04 20:00:00 | 2018-02-05 02:00:00+06 | Monday    |         1
 (0,7)  | 2018-02-05 00:00:00 | 2018-02-05 06:00:00+06 | Monday    |         1
 (0,8)  | 2018-02-05 04:00:00 | 2018-02-05 10:00:00+06 | Monday    |         1
 (0,9)  | 2018-02-05 08:00:00 | 2018-02-05 14:00:00+06 | Monday    |         1
 (0,10) | 2018-02-05 12:00:00 | 2018-02-05 18:00:00+06 | Monday    |         1
 (0,11) | 2018-02-05 16:00:00 | 2018-02-05 22:00:00+06 | Monday    |         1
 (0,48) | 2018-02-11 20:00:00 | 2018-02-12 02:00:00+06 | Monday    |         1
 (0,49) | 2018-02-12 00:00:00 | 2018-02-12 06:00:00+06 | Monday    |         1
 (0,50) | 2018-02-12 04:00:00 | 2018-02-12 10:00:00+06 | Monday    |         1
 (0,51) | 2018-02-12 08:00:00 | 2018-02-12 14:00:00+06 | Monday    |         1
 (0,52) | 2018-02-12 12:00:00 | 2018-02-12 18:00:00+06 | Monday    |         1
 (0,53) | 2018-02-12 16:00:00 | 2018-02-12 22:00:00+06 | Monday    |         1
(12 rows)

t=# set TimeZone to 'UTC+6:00';
SET
t=# select ctid,filter_datetime at time zone 'UTC' utc, filter_datetime,to_char(filter_datetime,'Day'), extract(dow from filter_datetime)
from xyz
where extract(dow from filter_datetime) = 1
order by 1;
  ctid  |         utc         |    filter_datetime     |  to_char  | date_part
--------+---------------------+------------------------+-----------+-----------
 (0,9)  | 2018-02-05 08:00:00 | 2018-02-05 02:00:00-06 | Monday    |         1
 (0,10) | 2018-02-05 12:00:00 | 2018-02-05 06:00:00-06 | Monday    |         1
 (0,11) | 2018-02-05 16:00:00 | 2018-02-05 10:00:00-06 | Monday    |         1
 (0,12) | 2018-02-05 20:00:00 | 2018-02-05 14:00:00-06 | Monday    |         1
 (0,13) | 2018-02-06 00:00:00 | 2018-02-05 18:00:00-06 | Monday    |         1
 (0,14) | 2018-02-06 04:00:00 | 2018-02-05 22:00:00-06 | Monday    |         1
 (0,51) | 2018-02-12 08:00:00 | 2018-02-12 02:00:00-06 | Monday    |         1
 (0,52) | 2018-02-12 12:00:00 | 2018-02-12 06:00:00-06 | Monday    |         1
 (0,53) | 2018-02-12 16:00:00 | 2018-02-12 10:00:00-06 | Monday    |         1
 (0,54) | 2018-02-12 20:00:00 | 2018-02-12 14:00:00-06 | Monday    |         1
 (0,55) | 2018-02-13 00:00:00 | 2018-02-12 18:00:00-06 | Monday    |         1
 (0,56) | 2018-02-13 04:00:00 | 2018-02-12 22:00:00-06 | Monday    |         1
(12 rows)
```

as you see clients with different TimeZone sees different rows as Monday. This is because `timestamptz` keeps time in UTC - not in client time zone. Converting it when returning to client.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html

> For timestamp with time zone, the internally stored value is always in
>   UTC (Universal Coordinated Time, traditionally known as Greenwich Mean
>   Time, GMT). An input value that has an explicit time zone specified is
>   converted to UTC using the appropriate offset for that time zone. If
>   no time zone is stated in the input string, then it is assumed to be
>   in the time zone indicated by the system's TimeZone parameter, and is
>   converted to UTC using the offset for the timezone zone.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html